# Do you HAVE to enable My Domain if you want to use Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, mydomain

So as the title says - is it a MUST that My Domain is enabled in order to use SFDX/Salesforce CLI?

I'm trying to persuade the business to move to SFDX but they have tonnes of integrations and customisations. I don't really want the additional time/risk of enabling My Domain if I can help it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs:

> If you don’t enable and deploy My Domain, you can’t link your
>   namespace to the Dev Hub org.

So unless you want to use namespace in your SFDX scratch org you don't need to enable My domain. So in your case you don't need to enable my domain.

[Review Org Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_before_org_setup.htm)

Comment: Thank you!! Knew I'd read something regarding a dependency somewhere!

Comment: @ForceHero If you're not an ISV, you're good.